# i want to make sms app I have list view that have the numbers of people who text me but the names is repeated

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, arraylist, sms

i want to make sms app I have list view that have the numbers of people who text me but the names is repeated
my code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Cursor cursor;
        ListView listView;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView=findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayList<String> contacts =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contacts);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null, null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String body  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                contacts.add("from: "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"))
+"\n"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            }
        }
```

if i removed `+"\n"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));`
from the while loop i will have the numbers of all the people that text me
**And if someone sends me more than once, his number will be repeated more than once**
[this is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Tx48.jpg)

what should i do to have one of each number in the list view

Hope it is understood

Comment: did you mean contacts have duplicate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the while loop to

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String x = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            if (!check.contains(x)){
                contacts.add(x);
            }
        }
```